# Is it possible to use "swing" for only one staff in Musescore?

Tags: musescore

I have an arrangement which is played in swing through the whole song. Now, I want to remove swing for a short section, but only for one staff. Is that possible? It's meant for the playback.

Comment: Is this just for a score, or for playback?

Comment: @Richard for playback

Comment: I think for the notation you want to put in a line above that says "straight 8ths" (or 16ths or whatever). I'm not sure if you can affect playback on only one staff though.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer:  Yes in Sibelius, Dorico and Finale (current versions) but No for MuseScore.  In MuseScore 'Swing' and 'Straight' affect all the staves.

I don't think there's even any way to cheat it in MuseScore by micro-editing individual notes. Individual velocity, and even tuning, can be edited, but not playback position. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unusual to notate swung notes on the staff. Typically, the notation I see as Todd notes is the beginning of the tune is notated "Swing Feel" and then text notation for "Straight 8ths" for the straight part.

Some people like to put this in after "Swing Feel"
[image]
but honestly true swing feel is not played strictly like this and actually playing this accurately will sound clunky.